# From Shortened Code to Reed Muller code

Tags: coding-theory

[Ok people, before scolding me, let me tell you this thing is giving me headaches..]

I have a $C$ = $C(8,3)$ described by this matrix:

$$G=\begin {bmatrix}
1&0&0&1&0&1&1&0\\
0&1&0&1&1&1&1&1\\
0&0&1&1&0&0&1&0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I've been asked get a shortened code of $C$. I got:

$$G'=\begin {bmatrix}
1&0&1&0&1&1&0\\
0&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

(Started from the very beginning in order to show you "where I'm coming from")

I should try to find a Reed-Muller code from $C'$.

As far as I know,  $n = 2^m$ and $k = \sum_{i=1}^{r} 1 + \binom mi$ with hamming distance $d = 2^{m-r}$.

But if $d = 4$ and $n = 7$, $m$ (that should be an integer) in those formulas seems not matching at all. Am I doing something wrong?

Also, when calculating $k$, since $r$ is the upper bound of a sum, how big should it be?

but, my BIG question is, is it possible to get a Reed-Muller code from this matrix?

Comment: May be you should check whether this is a shortened or punctured Reed-Muller code. As you observed the length won't match otherwise. But even so, the dimension $k$ won't match, if you only shorten it once (i.e. statr with $m=3$). It may be possible to get $C$, by shortening the $(16,11,4)$ Reed-Muller code ($m=4, r=2$) in eight positions. But that code has then been "shortened to death", so I wouldn't call it a Reed-Muller code any longer in that case. The exercise is a bit weird actually. Was there a reason why you shortened at the third bit in particular when going from $C$ to $C'$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Hi, thanks! well, that's an exercise for test and it ask (after creating a parity matrix) that, in order to protect from errors a transmission source (of 4 codewords, same probability) I have to short this C code (and encode those codewords with C'). I think I can handle this problem. 4 equiprobable codewords could be {00, 01, 10, 11}.About your question: if I removed the last bit, was it good the same to have a third column made by all zeroes?